# Pass array to from one function to another and perform parameter expansion

Tags: bash

The below utility script does all kinds of tarring for client scripts. It does absolute-to-relative path conversions many times so I extracted that into a separate function (`_convertToRelative`).

```sh
#!/bin/bash

_convertToRelative() {
  local -n arr1=$1
  local arr2=( "${arr1[@]/#\//}" )  # ( /foo/bar /foo/baz ) -> ( foo/bar foo/baz )
  echo $arr2 
}

tarPaths() {
  local -n paths_absolute=$1
  local paths_relative=${_convertToRelative paths_absolute}   # fails here
  # ...run tar
}
```

A client script would do this

```sh
paths=( '/foo/bar/baz/a' '/foo/bar/baz/b' '/foo/bar/baz/c' )
tarPaths paths
```

But it fails with:

> paths_relative=${_convertToRelative paths_absolute}: bad substitution

Comment: ${}, are you sure you don't need $() (brackets instead of accolades)?

Comment: the `paths_absolute` needs a `$` since it is a variable...

Comment: @Dominique YES that was it! Thanks!

Comment: @Jetchisel No it is passed by reference so doesn't need a `$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass variable `paths_relative` as reference too. Then you don't need to `echo` the array as string and convert that back to an array which could lead to problems if a path contains spaces, tabs or newlines:

```
#!/bin/bash

_convertToRelative() {
  local -n arr1=$1 arr2=$2
  arr2=( "${arr1[@]#/}" )  # <- remove shortest prefix `/` from each array element
}

tarPaths() {
  local -n paths_absolute=$1
  local -a paths_relative
  _convertToRelative paths_absolute paths_relative
  # ...run tar
}
```

Comment: GNU `tar` strips the leading slashes from filenames unless option `-P` is used. Do you really need the function?

Comment: Yeah it was just an example, but I have this need (for "helper" functions that take arrays) for many other callsites too. Your code is really neat, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a typo: Instead of `${...}`, you need to type `$(...)` (brackets instead of accolades).

Comment: Thanks! And also, the `_convertToRelative` function needs to return a string rather than array, like so: `echo "${arr2[@]}"`. Then the caller wraps that into a new array.